# Add a verticle line between matplotlib subplots

Tags: python, matplotlib

[image: I have this subplots here]
Hello, I have made this subplots, here the images are in 4 columns, my idea is to compare them in a pair of two, that is, 1st column with 2nd and 3rd with 4th. But here it is bit confusing the way it looks right now. Is it possible to add a vertical line between 2nd and 3rd column somehow?? So that it seems like first two column are together and the other two are pairs? Is there any possible way to do it?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

indexes = [1000,1001]

indexes2 = [1010,1011]
columns = 4
rows = len(indexes)
f, axarr = plt.subplots(rows, columns,figsize=(10,10))
k = 0
for i in range(0, rows):
    axarr[i, 0].set_title(str(indexes[k])+"-Patch 1",fontsize=15)    
    axarr[i, 1].set_title(str(indexes[k])+"-Patch 2",fontsize=15)

    axarr[i, 2].set_title(str(indexes2[k])+"-Patch 1",fontsize=15)    
    axarr[i, 3].set_title(str(indexes2[k])+"-Patch 2",fontsize=15)

    k = k+1
    axarr[i, 0].set_xticks([])
    axarr[i, 1].set_xticks([])
    axarr[i, 0].set_yticks([])
    axarr[i, 1].set_yticks([])

    axarr[i, 2].set_xticks([])
    axarr[i, 3].set_xticks([])
    axarr[i, 2].set_yticks([])
    axarr[i, 3].set_yticks([])

plt.tight_layout()
```

I have added the code how I got the subplots up. If it is helpful in answering the question. Thank you for your time. :)

If the question is not clear, I need a line like this, I added in image editor in the following image.
[image: Image with line that I need]

Comment: Please add [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Well, I can not share the whole dataset, rest of the code is already here. So may be I can create another demo with sample images. Please give me few moments.

Comment: I updated the minimal code, in the main question, i realized what are the images really are does not matter in this context right?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Line

Adding a line is as easy as

```
line = plt.Line2D((.5,.5),(.1,.9), color="k", linewidth=3)
fig.add_artist(line)
```

[image]

```css
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

a = np.random.rand(10,10,8)
columns = 4
rows = a.shape[2]//columns

fig, axarr = plt.subplots(rows, columns)
fig.subplots_adjust(left=0.1, right=0.9,  wspace=0.4)

for i, ax in enumerate(axarr.flat):
    img = a[:,:,i]
    ax.imshow(img)
    ax.set_title("-Patch {}".format(i))    

line = plt.Line2D((.5,.5),(.1,.9), color="k", linewidth=3)
fig.add_artist(line)

plt.show()
```

For a more sophisticated solution with lines, see [Draw a separator or lines between subplots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26084231/draw-a-separator-or-lines-between-subplots/55465138#55465138)

### Space

However, potentially you would rather adjust the spacing between the plots.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.gridspec import GridSpec
import numpy as np

a = np.random.rand(10,10,8)
columns = 4
rows = a.shape[2]//columns


fig = plt.figure()
axarr1 = fig.subplots(2,2, gridspec_kw=dict(left=0.05, right=0.43, wspace=0.4))
axarr2 = fig.subplots(2,2, gridspec_kw=dict(left=0.57, right=0.95, wspace=0.4))


for i, ax in enumerate(axarr1.flat):
    img = a[:,:,i]
    ax.imshow(img)
    ax.set_title("-Patch {}".format(i)) 

for i, ax in enumerate(axarr2.flat):
    img = a[:,:,i+4]
    ax.imshow(img)
    ax.set_title("-Patch {}".format(i+4)) 


plt.show()
```

This allows to visually separate the two groups of subplots without having some black line in the plot.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for the line solution, that was something I was looking for. Double thank you and +1 for the second solution, that is something I NEED!

Comment: Hi, Just to clarify , gs1 = GridSpec(2, 2, left=0.05, right=0.48, wspace=0.05)
gs2 = GridSpec(2, 2, left=0.52, right=0.95, wspace=0.05) this lines are not really needed right since the gridspec_kw is instantiated anyways , right ? @ImportanceOfBeingErnest

Comment: Ups, sorry, I was typing in two potential solutions and forgot to delete one of them.