# How to draw a separator or lines between subplots (when subplots have titles, axis labels etc)

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to draw a line or some kind of separator between subplots.

**I am well aware of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26084231/draw-a-separator-or-lines-between-subplots), but I couldn't get the solution given there to work, as I explain below.**

I (sort of) understand these [transformations](https://matplotlib.org/users/transforms_tutorial.html), but the fundamental question I have, which would clarify everything else, is: **is there a way to identify the "real" bottom left of each subplot as the (0,0) point of some transformation?** Or, once you start adding titles, labels, etc, can these items mes up the coordinate system, eg an axis label may end up with y coordinates < 0?

**Plotting a line using the plot() method of each axis**, and using transform=axis.transAxes, so that (0,0) is the bottom left and (1,1) is the top right **does draw a line, but:**

- drawing it from (0,0) to (1,0) draws it at the bottom of the axis; I need it farther below, below the x_axis label etc
- determining the exact coordinates where to plot it, exactly how much below, is cumbersome, as that depends on what elements are present in the figure: titles,
  labels etc.
- The line end ups beneath the other elements of the
  figure, and the output is very messy

The second solution given at that link uses `blended_transform_factory` , but, to be honest, I couldn't get the syntax to work.

A toy example is:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
import seaborn as sns

sns.set(style='darkgrid')

n = int(100)
x = np.arange(0,n)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(3,2)

for i,a in enumerate(ax.flatten() ):
    y = np.random.rand(n)
    sns.lineplot(x, y, ax=a)
    a.set_title('Chart # ' + str(i+1))
    a.set_xlabel('my x')
    a.set_ylabel('my y')

    # this is the first solution; messy output, line behind other elements of the figure
    a.plot([-1, 1.5], [-0.2, -0.2], color='black', lw=0.5, transform=a.transAxes, clip_on=False)
```

The second solution would mean replacing the last line with those below (always within the for loop):

```
trans = matplotlib.transforms.blended_transform_factory(fig.transFigure, a.transAxes)
line = matplotlib.lines.Line2D([0, 1], [0,0], color='w', transform=trans)
fig.lines.append(line)
```

I must have done this incorrectly, because, while the first solution at least draws something, this draws nothing at all - but no errors are given.

Comment: I suppose the second solution doesn't appear because a white line on white background is not visible. There is no predefined coordinate system that has the bottom of the textlabels as (0,0). You can use axes coordinates and a negative number as you do here; you can also get the window extent of the texts and transform them to any coordinate system to find out where to best draw the line. The more accurate the solution, the more complex it will get.

Comment: white line - how clumsy of me :( How would I get the window extent of labels titles etc? On a related note, is there a way to make sure the x_label of one plot and the title of the plot below do not overlap?

Comment: I answered the [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55465138/4124317).

Comment: That's great - thank you so much!